# Javascript named export exports everything, not only what was named

Tags: javascript, events, import, export

I have a JS module with functions that I would like to export, the same file also has JQuery events, like `on click` events, when I export only the functions I want the events are also exported which causes them to be duplicated on my website.

How can I export only the functions I want?

Example code:
File 1:

```
function a {...}
function b {...}

(function() {...})();
$('asdf').on('click', function(event) {...});

export{ a, b };
```

File 2:

```
import { a, b } from './file1.js';

// Events appear here too!
```

I'm using webpack and generating one JS file for each module.

Comment: Do you want to export "onclick" too or only a and b?

Comment: Only `a` and `b`. The problem is that the `onclick` is also exported and I don't want to export it.

Answer (score 0):

I change import statement like this

This is worked for me.

*file1.js*

```
function a() {
     console.log("foo");
}
function b() {
    console.log("bar");
}

(function() {})();
$('asdf').on('click', function(event) {});

export{ a, b };
```

*main.js*

```
import * as MyFn from './file1'

MyFn.a();
MyFn.b();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem for me.